# unit testing spyOn observable service in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

I have a service (ChildService) which depends on another service (InteractWithServerService). The latter service (InteractWithServerService) is used to make server calls and return an observable of "any" type. For simplicity let's assume it returns an observable. I am trying to write a unit test for ChildService.

ChildService

```
@Injectable()
export class ApplicationService {
    constructor(private  interactWithServerService:InteractWithServerService){;}

    public GetMeData():string {
        var output:string;       
        this.interactWithServerService.get("api/getSomeData").
           subscribe(response =>{console.log("server response:", response);
           output=response});        
         return output;
    }
}
```

ServerInteractionService

```
@Injectable()
export class InteractWithServerService {        
    constructor(private http: Http) {
        ;
    }    
    get(url: string): Observable<any> {        
        return this.http.get(this.url);
    }       
}
```

The test case works fine when I mock the dependent service. i.e.,

```
class MockInteractWithServerService {
    get() {
        return Observable.of("some text");
    }           
}

describe('Service:ChildService', () => {
    let childService: ChildService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
             { provide: InteractWithServerService, useClass: MockInteractWithServerService },
                ChildService],
        });


    beforeEach(inject([ChildService], (actualService: ChildService) => {
        childService= actualService;        
    }));

    fit('should call server-call testCall()', () => {
        let actualReturnvalue= childService.GetMeData();        
        expect(actualReturnvalue).toBe("some text");
    });
});
```

The above method is not preferred as I might end up writing "n" mock classes for "n" dependencies. So I want to create my unit tests using spyOn.
However, the test case doesn't work and throws "Error: No provider for Http!". While I understand what the error is, I would like to know why it is thrown although I am spying on the dependent service. Looks like the "spyOn" is not working.

```
describe('Service:ChildService', () => {
    let childService: ChildService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
             InteractWithServerService,
                ChildService],
        });

        spyOn(InteractWithServerService.prototype, 'get').and
             .callFake(()=>      
          {return Observable.of("some text");});       
    });
    beforeEach(inject([ChildService], (actualService: ChildService) => {
        childService= actualService;        
    }));

    fit('should call server-call testCall()', () => {
        let actualReturnvalue= childService.GetMeData();        
        expect(actualReturnvalue).toBe("some text");
    });
});
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> However, the test case doesn't work and throws "Error: No provider for Http!".

Because you still have the service in the `providers`, so Angular is trying to create it still

```
providers: [
 InteractWithServerService,
    ChildService],
```

What you can do instead of creating a mock *class* is to just do something like

```
providers: [
  { 
    provide: InteractWithServerService,
    useValue: { get: Observable.of(..) }
  }
]
```

Here's you're using `useValue` which provide any object. That will be the value used when injected. In the case above, it is just some arbitrary object with your mock method.

If you want to spy so that you can provide different values, you could inject the `InteractWithServerService`, and then do

```
spyOn(service, 'get').and.returnValue(Observable.of(...))
// do test
```

Another thing you could do is mock the Http with a dummy object

```
{ provide: Http, useValue: {} }
```

Now the `InteractWithServerService` will work (just adding the class to the providers` like you currently have). And you can just spy on it

```
let service = TestBed.get(InteractWithServerService);
spyOn(service, 'get').and.returnValue(..)
// do test
```

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet. Works like a charm. Only thing that concerns is "useValue" and returning a arbitrary object for each method you will be calling. It definitely looks dirty (rather not so clean). Is this the way angular wants us to write the tests?

Comment: An "arbitrary object" is not really any different from using a mock class. Only difference is that one is encapsulated in a class. In the end they are both just arbitrary objects. Your class does not extend the real service interface. What makes that not arbitrary? All that matters is that the object has the method that will be called.

Comment: No way I am arguing that mock classes are better than useValue. My point is both - mock class and useValue solution doesn't look clean when compared  to old way just injecting the dependent classes and spying on them.

Comment: What if the service has 5 dependencies, and what if those dependencies have dependencies, and so on? You will have to configure the infrastructure to inject all of those services. It's a lot of work, when all you need to do is mock it. If you look at the Angular docs for testing, you will see that they do make use of mocks.

Comment: I am trying to use `spyOn(service, 'get').and.returnValue(Observable.of(...))` but having a `Cannot find name 'Observable'` error. What is the import I am missing?

Comment: Found it out. To use `Observable.of()` is needed this imports: `import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';`

Comment: Hello, i wanted to know that can we call returnValue 2 times inside the same "it()" with different values such that the component gets and renders both of them, or will it override some?

Answer (score 3):

Using jasmin 2.6.2: `get` is a function so you need to add the arrow function notation to the answer above:

```
providers: [
  { 
    provide: InteractWithServerService,
    useValue: { get: () => Observable.of(..) }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another more elegant way I found is to spy on the observable property and return a value, after which you flush within a fakeAsync. This will allow you to test the code inside your subscribe.

**Simplified Version**

*.ts File*

```
   private isThereWork(): void {
    this.subscription.add(this.work$
    .subscribe((hasWork: boolean) => {
      this.displayWorkItems = hasWork;
      })
    );
  }
```

*.spec.ts*

```
fit('should work be displayed', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOnProperty<any>(component, 'work$', 'get').and.returnValue(of(false));

    component['isThereWork']();
    flush();
    expect(component.displayWorkItems ).toBe(false);
  }));
```

Hope this helps. I thought this a game changer when I found out.

Comment: This assumes work$ has a getter